# Как я могу сделать вывод ссылки, которая была найдена по совпадению?

Tags: python, bs4

Я пытаюсь написать программу, которая будет находить монеты по заданному параметру (`coins_list`). Но моя программа работает некорректно и находит монеты с параметром и без него и выводить их все. Как я могу это исправить? Пожалуйста, помогите мне.

Мой код:

```
s = requests.Session()
    response = s.get(url=url, headers=headers)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
    page_list = int(soup.find_all('li', class_='page')[-1].text)

    coin_api_list = []
    coins_list = ["HEX"]

    for page in range(1, page_list + 1):

        r = requests.get(url = f'https://coinmarketcap.com/?page={page}', headers=headers)
        soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

        find_coin_href = soup.findAll('div',class_='sc-16r8icm-0 escjiH')
        for coin_name in find_coin_href:
            coin_name = soup.findAll('p',class_='sc-1eb5slv-0 iworPT')
            for check_name in coin_name:
                check_name = check_name.text
                if check_name in coins_list:

                    for links in find_coin_href:
                        for link in links.findAll('a',href=True):
                            main_link=baseurl+link['href']
                            if main_link not in coin_api_list:
                                coin_api_list.append(main_link)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

```
from requests import Session
from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError, Timeout, TooManyRedirects
import json

url = 'https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemultifull?fsyms=BTC,ETH,XPR,LUNA,BNB,MATIC,SOL,ADA,SAND,BUSD,NEAR&tsyms=USD'

headers = {
    'Accepts': 'application/json',
    'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': 'API KEY',
}

session = Session()

try:
    response = session.get(url)
    data = json.loads(response.text)
    print(data) # Вывод ключей
except (ConnectionError, Timeout, TooManyRedirects) as e:
    print(e)


def btc_fiat(crypto, money, eur):
    price = data['RAW'][crypto][money][eur]

    print(crypto, price)



serch = ('BTC', 'ETH', 'XPR', 'LUNA', 'BNB', 'MATIC', 'SOL', 'ADA', 'SAND', 'BUSD','NEAR')

for i in serch:
    btc_fiat(i,'USD','OPENHOUR') # Цена открытия из search
    btc_fiat(i,'USD','LOWHOUR') # Цена закрытия из search
```

Comment: Отредактируй под себя, до конца не ясно что конкретно вы хотите.